# How can I sort the same "headers" in Python to Sql Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I want the same "headeres" to come together when I insert in to the database.

I use Python as a programming language and Microsoft SQL Server as database.

Below I give an example of my question.

This is what I have:

```
A B C A B C A B C 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is what I want:

```
A B C
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
7 8 9
```

This the code that I work with:

```
 cursor = get_sql_conn().cursor()
    localFile = 'C:\\Users\\dersimw\\Source\Repos\\nordpoolAnalyse\\data\\2011-3.xlsx'
    excelFile = pd.ExcelFile(localFile)
    sheetsList = []
    rowsID = []

    for allTheSheets in range(1,32):
        convertingToChar = '%02d' % allTheSheets
        sheetsList.append(str(convertingToChar))

    for sheets in sheetsList:
        df = excelFile.parse(sheets, skiprows=35)
        df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace = True)
        df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

        selectedColumns = df.iloc[: , [0,1,2,3,4]]
        transposeColumns = selectedColumns.transpose()
        print(transposeColumns)

    for key, rows in transposeColumns.items():
       # print("## Column: ", key, "\n")
        columnInsertSql = "INSERT INTO DataSetValues (BuyAmount, BuyAggregated, BuyPrice, SellAmount, SellAggregated, SellPrice) VALUES("
        columnCounter = 1
        columnHasData = False

        for key, column in rows.items():
            if isinstance(column, int) or isinstance(column, float):
                columnHasData = True
                columnInsertSql += str(column)

                if columnCounter != len(list(rows.items())):
                    columnInsertSql += ", "
                    columnCounter += 1

        columnInsertSql += ")"
        if columnHasData == True:
            cursor.execute(columnInsertSql)
            print("## SQL: " + columnInsertSql)
            cursor.commit()
```

Comment: So, the `A B C A B C A B C ` is your column header ?

Comment: Yes Yogesh, in this example

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the neates solution but it works as intented:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create dummy dataframe reppresting what you get from your SQL:
head = ['A','B','C']*3
rows = [[i for i in range(1,10)] for i in range(0,3)]
# put it in a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=head)
my_dic = {}
for name, group in df.transpose().groupby(level=0):
    my_dic[name] = group.values.reshape(np.size(group.values))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dic)
```

Output:

```
new_df
Out[1]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6
5  4  5  6
6  7  8  9
7  7  8  9
8  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thank you Gozy4, I tried this but i get the error message:     for name, group in dff.transpose.groupby(level =0):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis when calling the method `transpose`: `df.transpose().grupby()``; Btw you can only create the dataframe from the dictionary if you have the same amount of columns A,B,C.

Comment: Edit your question and put the relevant code in the question. This way it is also searchable in the future.